# what does stack and queues refer to in programming?

Tags: memory, stack

what does stack and queues refer to in programming such as java , javascript, php etc

Comment: I fail to see a question in body.

Comment: because it wont let me

Comment: the question is only the title

Comment: You could have just googled this by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

A stack is a LastInFirstOut data structure.

[image: Stack Picture]

A queue is a FirstInFirstOut data structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you want FIFO behavior of a collection of objects use QUEUE, whereas for LIFO behavior use STACK